# Substitution with a list file

Tags: sed

I'm trying to automatize the creation of an index (the original file has been created with LyX, but it doesn't matter here, I don't want to use the Lyx tool).

For each word I want to index I need to insert, just after each occurence of the word, the following code (with "foo" as example here):

```
\begin_inset Index idx
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout
Foo
\end_layout

\end_inset
```

So, for the moment I use sed:

```
sed -i 's/foo/foo\n\\begin_inset Index idx\nstatus open\n\n\\begin_layout Plain Layout\nFoo\n\\end_layout\n\n\\end_inset\n\n/g' myfile.lyx
```

It works, but as I need to index tons of word I'd like to do the same using a file containing a list of all the words I want to index.

For example, I have a file1 containing:

```
blablabla foo blablabla bar
blaba bar blabla word
```

And a list file (file2) containing:

```
foo
bar
word
```

And I want my file1 as that:

```
blablabla foo
\begin_inset Index idx
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout
Foo
\end_layout

\end_inset


blablabla bar
\begin_inset Index idx
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout
Bar
\end_layout

\end_inset


blaba bar
\begin_inset Index idx
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout
Bar
\end_layout

\end_inset


blabla word
\begin_inset Index idx
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout
Word
\end_layout

\end_inset
```

What is the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 2):

If your sed supports `-r` (or `-E`) then you can use pattern alternation:

```
sed -r 's/(foo|bar|word)/\1\n\\begin_inset Index idx\nstatus open\n\n\\begin_layout Plain Layout\n\1\n\\end_layout\n\n\\end_inset\n\n/g'
```

Basically put the words in the first section as `(word1|word2|word3|...)` and then you can reference it as `\1` in the replace section to put back exactly the word that was matched.

It's then simple enough to build the first pattern from the file.  For example,

```
list=$(tr '\012' '|' < listfile)
list="(${list%?})"
```

Comment: It's a good idea, but I have about 300 words to index... That's why using a list file would be better.

Comment: Added an example to show how the list expression could be built up

Comment: I didn't understand how to build the list with your example. But it inspired me so I did a : `cat list | xargs -d '\n' -i sed -ri 's/{}/{}\n\\begin_inset Index
idx\nstatus open\n\n\\begin_layout Plain
Layout\n\u{}\n\\end_layout\n\n\\end_inset\n\n/g' myfile.lyx`